# Is It Possible to Use a String as an Index?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In other languages you can use strings as keys -

PHP:

```
$array['string'] = 50; 
$array['anotherstring'] = 150;
```

Is this possible in VBA?

Comment: @JackOrangeLantern -- please stop the excessive editing.  You're flooding the Active Questions list with trivial edits to **years-old** questions, when a majority of the users use the Active List to keep track of changes to NEW questions.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Ah, I will cease. I attempted to correct my errors, then strictly followed editing policy when I was reading posts. I thought all posts supposed to be edited, and many of the old posts seem to be disconnected from the present. Nevertheless, I will research what is a "trivial edit" again, and try to determine the minimum number of edits necessary to be non-trivial. I am uncertain as to the criteria now. Can you point me to a link or a series of links?

Comment: @JackOrangeLantern - Here are a few links on Meta:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116656/too-minor-edit-reason-can-sometimes-be-a-little-contradictory, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122923/why-can-suggested-edits-be-too-minor, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110153/approve-suggested-edits-when-only-the-signature-is-removed

Comment: Thanks @LittleBobbyTables. Unfortunately, I am uncertain as to a deterministic criteria, and I do not want to be flagged again for misunderstanding the editing rules, for I which I cannot find a cohesive and centralized policy page. Moreover, there seem to be implicit rules that remain undetailed but simply known by experienced editors. I will cease editing and leave it to those with far more points/experience. I will use questions/answers to further my learning, which was my initial path. Thank you for correcting my course. I apologize for the flood and leave the editing to you and others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VBA you can create a Collection object.  Items in the collection can be accessed by index (Long integer) or by a string key.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the Dictionary object?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164502(office.10).aspx

Comment: What would be the advantage of a Dictionary object over a simple collection?

Comment: You can iterate over the keys of a Dictionary object, which you cannot do with a collection. Also, you can define the behaviour of the keys as being case-sensitive or case-insensitive, as needed. Collection keys are always case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used VBA in a long time, but those are not arrays, they are [hashes](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2006/11/02/all-about-hashes.html) (in perl) and [associative arrays](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2001/06/21/php_foundations.html) (in PHP).  If you are looking for an answer, you might get better results searching for one of those terms and VBA instead of just "array".

As far as I know, there is no native hash table type in VBA, but like I said, it has been a while since I used it, so I may be wrong.